# 250gb SSD harddisk, but only 170gb is available

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, snap

Can anyone explain why I only have 170gb space? I thought I had 1gb swap and rest on root partition. Or can anyone point me towards a direction where I can read more on this topic? Is it because of all the snaps?

[image]
[image]

Output of df:

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          8136852         0   8136852   0% /dev
tmpfs                         1633432      2048   1631384   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 238325496 177376756  48772768  79% /
tmpfs                         8167156    628488   7538668   8% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         8167156         0   8167156   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2                      98944     98944         0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/loop4                      56704     56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop1                     158848    158848         0 100% /snap/code/42
/dev/loop3                      56320     56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop5                      63616     63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop6                      99328     99328         0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop8                     170752    170752         0 100% /snap/postman/123
/dev/loop7                      44288     44288         0 100% /snap/snap-store/415
/dev/loop9                      58752     58752         0 100% /snap/discord/112
/dev/loop0                     148480    148480         0 100% /snap/code/41
/dev/loop10                     56192     56192         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop12                     40576     40576         0 100% /snap/remmina/4324
/dev/loop11                     39936     39936         0 100% /snap/remmina/4309
/dev/loop13                    144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/100
/dev/loop14                     58752     58752         0 100% /snap/discord/109
/dev/loop15                    147712    147712         0 100% /snap/slack/25
/dev/loop16                    165376    165376         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop17                    170752    170752         0 100% /snap/postman/122
/dev/loop18                      2304      2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop19                    297984    297984         0 100% /snap/vlc/1620
/dev/loop21                     51072     51072         0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/loop20                    297472    297472         0 100% /snap/vlc/1700
/dev/loop22                    261760    261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop24                    144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop23                      2304      2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop25                    164096    164096         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop26                    261760    261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop27                    121856    121856         0 100% /snap/slack/27
tmpfs                         1633428        48   1633380   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb2                   226665468 205766000  20899468  91% /media/simon/5E9C7F549C7F25A5
```

Comment: Your root filesystem is roughly 240 GB with roughly 180 GB used, and roughly 50 GB free. You are using LVM. You may be able to expand the root logical volume depending on your LVM configuration.

Comment: You might be confused because the second screenshot you show suggests you have 170.9GB in total on /, but it seems that this tool only shows you the used amount, which is in fact around 170GB according to df.